# UDT existence in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

How to check whether table has UDT or not and if yes, how to get list of UDT's in a given table in SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT c.[name] AS ColumnName, ct.[name] AS UDTName
FROM sys.tables t 
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
     JOIN sys.types ct ON c.user_type_id = ct.user_type_id
WHERE t.[name] = 'YourTableName'
  AND ct.is_user_defined = 1;
```

Comment: @marc_s thanks for correcting the typo on `ColumnName`, but please don't change my SQL to your formatting preferences. :)

Comment: it works, for full table name we can use "  Where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[Schema].[TableName]') "

Comment: SELECT * FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('[Schema].[TableName]') AND t.is_user_defined = 1